# AngularJS Carousel not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, carousel

[image]I'm trying to insert a slideshow on my app.  Instead of the slideshow working as it should, I just get images stacked next to each other.

HTML:

```
 <head>

<!-- App JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-route.min.js">     </script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/carousel.js"></script>
  rel="stylesheet">
 </head>


<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
<div style="height: 305px">
<carousel interval="myInterval">
  <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </slide>
 </carousel>
  </div>
```

carousel.js controller:

```
    angular.module('financeApp').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  var slides = $scope.slides = [];
  $scope.addSlide = function() {
  var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
  slides.push({
  image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
  text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
    ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
 });
  };
  for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
  $scope.addSlide();
}
});
```

Comment: That second segment of code isn't your carousel directive, that's the controller. To get a better understanding of your problem it'd be helpful to see the code for the actual directive.

Comment: post your html and js codes, plunker or fiddle demo would be great

Comment: Thanks, I'm using an external script:

<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

you need latest angular version. check the [DOC](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started)

> AngularJS **(requires AngularJS 1.2.x, tested with 1.2.16)**
>
> Bootstrap CSS (tested with version 3.1.1). This version of the library (0.12.0) works only with Bootstrap CSS in version 3.x. 0.8.0 is the last version of this library that supports Bootstrap CSS in version 2.3.x.

you need to add 'bootstrap css' file also

Comment: I've updated the latest angular version.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: Your Plunker works, but it won't show up on my website.

Comment: did you add `angular.js` `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js` `bootstrap.min.css` files with suitable versions as the plunker ?